# Gradle failed to build when proguard is activated

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I am trying to release my Android application with Gradle.

Everything works, including the `./gradlew clean build assembleRelease` command.

However, as soon as I try to use proguard, Gradle fail to build the release version.

Here is the error I get (stack trace activated):

```
...
:OSkin:validateDebugSigning
:OSkin:packageDebug
:OSkin:assembleDebug
:OSkin:prepareReleaseDependencies
:OSkin:compileReleaseAidl
:OSkin:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:OSkin:mergeReleaseAssets
:OSkin:compileReleaseRenderscript
:OSkin:mergeReleaseResources
:OSkin:processReleaseManifest
:OSkin:processReleaseResources
:OSkin:compileRelease UP-TO-DATE
:OSkin:proguardRelease
ProGuard, version 4.9
Reading input...
Reading program directory [/home/geantvert/workspace/OSkinProject/OSkin/build/classes/release]
:OSkin:proguardRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':OSkin:proguardRelease'.
> Can't read [/home/geantvert/workspace/OSkinProject/OSkin/build/classes/release] (No such file or directory)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':OSkin:proguardRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:286)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTaskWithCacheLock(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:214)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:276)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:78)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:89)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Can't read [/home/geantvert/workspace/OSkinProject/OSkin/build/classes/release] (No such file or directory)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:230)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:200)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:178)
    at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:78)
    at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:197)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:79)
    at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask.proguard(ProGuardTask.java:958)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:248)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:248)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
    at proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:213)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:202)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:530)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:513)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at proguard.io.DirectoryPump.pumpDataEntries(DirectoryPump.java:50)
    at proguard.InputReader.readInput(InputReader.java:226)
    ... 75 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 42.363 secs
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'http://www.bugsense.com/gradle/'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.+'
    compile 'org.zeroturnaround:zt-zip:1.+'
    compile 'com.github.japgolly.android:svg-android:2.+'
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.1') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.+'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:1+'
    compile 'com.bugsense.trace:bugsense:3.5'

    //Google Drive SDK
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.+'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2+'

    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.+') {
        exclude(group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
        exclude(group: 'junit', module: 'junit')
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
    }
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.+') {
        exclude group: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.google-play-services'
    }
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.+') {
        exclude group: 'xpp3'
    }
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.+') {
        exclude group: 'xpp3'
    }

    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-plus:v1+'

    compile 'com.netflix.rxjava:rxjava-android:+'

    compile('com.github.frankiesardo:icepick:2+') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.+'
    }

//    compile (group: 'com.google.apis', name: 'google-api-services-youtube', version: 'v3-rev56-1.15.0-rc')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
                    storeFile file('path_to_file')
                    storePassword '***'
                    keyAlias '***'
                    keyPassword '***'
                }
    }

    buildTypes
            {
                release {
                    runProguard true
                    proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
                    proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.release 
               }
            }
}
```

Does anyone has an idea of what is the issue?

Regards

Edit: `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` works perfectly! and `./gradlew clean build assembleRelease` works if runProguard is set to off. So it's a 100% proGuard issue.

Comment: I was actually having a problem with proguard, and thanks to your code snippet it lead to me add my proguard-project.txt to my build.gradle and that solved my problem.  I wish the android gradle docs had it in the example.

Comment: Why do you have mavenCentral() twice in your build file?

Comment: One is for the plug-in, one for the dependencies.

Comment: For others having the same issue: Make sure to copy the above release buildType - especially in regard to proguardFile and make sure to have that proguard-project.txt in your module's directory AND include the lines from the answer in it. I made a mistake in that area and was wondering, why the -dontwarn statements didn't do anything...

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I've been battling this issue for the past few hours. Basically the proguard task will halt execution if there are any warnings. You can see the Proguard warnings, and the stacktrace, by adding `-d` to the build (as in: `gradle clean assembleRelease -d`). Note that the stacktrace mentions to "Please correct the above warnings first."

In order to just get to a point where the build would get through proguard, I had to add `-dontwarn` entries for packages it was complaining about to my `proguard-project.txt` file. Something along the lines of:

```
-dontwarn org.apache.lang.**
```

...etc

So put simply... do as the stacktrace instructs you to do. Fix the warnings! :)

BTW, I apologize, as I now recognize that the stacktrace in the original post is not quite the same as the one I encountered. However, I do feel my answer is helpful, as obviously I ended up here trying to search for answers to my issue.

Comment: Yes, same exact thing for me...this should be the solution, not the one above.  These can go in your proguard-project.txt file and just add that to the one in your release section. Mine looks like: 
-dontwarn android.webkit.*
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn com.newrelic.**

Comment: Nice. :) thanks a lot! I had implemented the "Samsung Pass SDK" so I had to add -dontwarn com.samsung.** 
Just in case somebody else is struggling there..

Comment: I think this the solution i need, any example how i can implementing -dontwarn org.apache.lang? is it on the gradle after the proguard-project.txt?

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, I don't understand why but it seems if I start two times the same task with the same parameters (proguard...) the second one is the good one.

But if the second one the parameters change, the task fail.

Hope it will help someone.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use -ignorewarnings at proguard-project.txt so you don't need to specify each package.

Answer (score -16):

Check that your **minifyEnabled** in build gradle is set to "**false**". Because when it will be "true" debugger while generating signed apk will give an error.

Comment: Signed APKs are no problem for debugging. But if you don't `minifyEnabled` then you quickly need `multiDexEnabled` — which is an even bigger pain then Proguard.

Comment: Multidex is WAYY less effort than proguard can be (just a couple changes needed) when one is using rxjava and retrolambda and kotlin and other dependencies... just puttin it out there.  That being said, we use both.  Proguard is important for release builds if you care at all about app security and would like to strip log statements for performance reasons.  I have spent WEEKS chasing down Proguard issues, whereas making the switch to multidex was literally a 10 minute effort.

Comment: If you are modifying some posts - do something useful. "Please help" will be rejected

Comment: This prevents obfuscation. Not a solution.