# Android Execution failed for task app:proguardRelease

Tags: android, proguard, android-gradle-plugin

I am unable to generate a signed APK for my app, I am stuck with the error java.io.IOException Execution failed for task:'app:proguardRelease' I have what I think is a basic gradle file see below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.okason.clients"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

The generated Proguard-rules.pro file is empty amd I have not touched the proguard-android.txt file in the SDK. I even tried to copy this file to the root of app to be the same location as the app.gradle file without success.

I tried to run this command gradlew.bat assembleRelease per this `[SO Question][1]` with success. Please can someone take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong. I have update the SDK and Android Studio to the latest versions.

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting? There's all sorts of IOExceptions.

Comment: Here is the error Execution failed for task:'app:proguardRelease

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by setting minifyEnabled true to minifyEnabled false in the app.gradle file

Comment: But that just turns Proguard off, doesn't it. What if I still want proguard enabled?

Comment: Sinenes's answer about using -nowarn should be the accepted answer. Not this.

Comment: the correct solution should solve include proguard enable

Answer (score 3):

I think Sir you can avoid the error without turning off the Proguard. Check this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481752/gradle-failed-to-build-when-proguard-is-activated) by Sir Eric Schlenz with regards to this issue. In order to just get to a point where the build would get through proguard, You have to add `-dontwarn` entries for packages it was complaining about to your `proguard-project.txt` file.