# i can't build app when use ProGuard in Android Studio

Tags: android, obfuscation, android-proguard

I am using lasted version of Android Studio, and i have **obfuscated** my project by **ProGuard** in `Android Studio`.

edit content of `Build.gradle`such as this :

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

but when start the build project, an error like that 
[image: see error]

warning Image : [image: see warning]

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you post the warnings just before the message you've highlighted in the link?

Comment: you need to **correct the above warnings first**. You didn't show the *above warnings*

Comment: @metalurgus, warning image has attached above post. please see and help me

Answer (score 0):

Simply add **-dontwarn com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview** to your proguard-rules.pro.

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue,try to change  minifyEnabled true to  `minifyEnabled false`.

And just refer this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481752/gradle-failed-to-build-when-proguard-is-activated)

Comment: try to make it false and check

Comment: When set to False, the file is created without any problems

Comment: please see the warning image in above post

Comment: setting minifyEnabled to false will disable ProGuard, which is completely wrong.

Comment: @metalurgus, can you help me? this is very important for me . tnx :(