# Error:(26, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using android studio 0.9.3 with gradle `'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'`

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.11"
    }

    signingConfigs{
        releaseConfig{
            storeFile file("xxxxxxx")
            storePassword = "xxxx"
            keyAlias = "xxxx"
            keyPassword = "xxxx"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig

            // adds version to file name
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                def file = variant.outputFile
                variant.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // You must install or update the Google Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    // You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
}
```

The project compiled before without any changes in that file,
I'm getting:
**Error:(26, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'**

How to fix that?

Comment: You can read this for reference: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system.  It will illuminate such questions for you.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

As far as I know `runProguard` was replaced with `minifyEnabled`. I am still not sure how to define the config for proguard but a Google search should help you to find out.

Edit:

For the `outFile` read here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/4_-5NvxuFB0 how they do it.

In short: they used a more complex version:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    variant.outputs.each { output ->

        def apk = output.outputFile;
        def newName;

        // newName = apk.name.replace(".apk", "-v" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-" + variant.buildType.name.toUpperCase() + ".apk");
        if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
            newName = apk.name.replace(".apk", "-v" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-release.apk");
        } else {
            newName = apk.name.replace(".apk", "-v" + defaultConfig.versionName + "-beta.apk");
        }

        output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName);

        if (output.zipAlign) {
            output.outputFile = new File(apk.parentFile, newName.replace("-unaligned", ""));
        }

        logger.info('INFO: Set outputFile to ' + output.outputFile + " for [" + output.name + "]");
    }
}
```

Comment: now it has problem with Error:(32, 0) Could not find property 'outputFile' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@1615795.

Comment: That is correct, read the changes under 0.14.0 to know the exact changes http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: I edited to reflect the error about outputFile (edit currently waiting peer review)

Comment: I have removed the duplicated `applicationVariants.all { variant ->` line but accepted the rest, thanks

Comment: i have same problem with different method: Gradle DSL method not found compileSdkVersion()

Answer (score 131):

Instead of using `runProguard` in your gradle file, try using `minifyEnabled`. This should fix the issue. `runProguard` is deprecated and soon be stop working.

**EDIT**

To use `minifyEnabled`, gradle should be updated to version 2.2 or above.

Comment: Error is now changed to--> "Gradle DSL method not found: 'minifyEnable()'"

Comment: did you have the latest gradle build system (2.2) installed?

Comment: I'm getting the same error. not found minifyEnable. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Varundroid Oh does it depend on 2.2 ? I have 2.1

Comment: @Varundroid I updated my gradle wrapper to --> //services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip :: but it still gives same error for minifyEnable()

Comment: Should be `minifyEnabled` (not `minifyEnable`)

Comment: How about shrinkResources, is that the same thing?

Answer (score 112):

Change in the app build.gradle file may help:

old:

```
buildTypes {
    release {

        runProguard false // this line has to be changed

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

new:

```
buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled false // new version

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: did what you suggested still getting the same error.

Answer (score 26):

If you are using version 0.14.0 or higher of the `gradle` plugin, you should replace "`runProguard`" with "`minifyEnabled`" in your `build.gradle` files.

Just add this.

```
 buildTypes {           
     release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
                }
            }
```

**`minifyEnabled false`** Means Build Type names cannot be *main or androidTest* (this is enforced by the plugin), and that they have to be unique to each other.

The new version of the Android `Gradle` plugin, can automatically remove unused resources. The big win here is that it removes unused resources not just from your own code, but more importantly from *libraries* you are using (e.g. where there are resources included to support features that you are not actually using from your app).

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov Glad to receive your comments . Happy coding

Answer (score 25):

As of **Gradle 0.14.4**, these errors are reported as compile-time errors.

So you have to replace `runProguard false/true` with `minifyEnabled false/true`

The changes are listed on [Android Developers Blog](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system).

Answer (score 21):

Migrating Gradle Projects to version 1.0.0 needs some easy renaming work, everything is described here:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0

For proguard you can simply rename 'runProguard' => 'minifyEnabled', for the others see below:

```
Renamed Properties in BuildTypes:    
runProguard => minifyEnabled
zipAlign => zipAlignEnabled
jniDebugBuild => jniDebuggable
renderscriptDebug => renderscriptDebuggable

Renamed Properties in ProductFlavors:    
flavorGroups => flavorDimensions
packageName => applicationId
testPackageName => testApplicationId
renderscriptSupportMode => renderscriptSupportModeEnabled
ProductFlavor.renderscriptNdkMode => renderscriptNdkModeEnabled
Other Name changes

InstrumentTest was renamed to androidTest.
```

Comment: I appreciate both the android docs as well as you highlighting them, but where do you find everything else from zipAlign going forwards?
There's neglect to mention in which files this will be found. I do not see them in my root gradle config file.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the update of the gradle android tools to 0.14.3.
Into your file "build.gradle" replace

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'
```

by:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.2'
```

Until they fix it…

Answer (score 1):

**runProguard** has been renamed to **minifyEnabled** in version 0.14.0 (2014/10/31) of Gradle.

To fix this, you need to change runProguard to minifyEnabled in the **build.gradle** file of your project.

[image]