# Could not find property 'outputFile' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

After updating to AS 1.0 RC 1 and plugin 0.14.4 I am having problems with the renaming part of my build.gradle:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            def file = variant.outputFile
            variant.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
        }
```

throws now:

```
Error:(78, 0) Could not find property 'outputFile' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@67e7625f.
```

and also I cannot jump to the class ApplicationVariantImpl to look how the property might have  been renamed. 
Anyone knows workarounds for this?

Comment: where r u defining defaultConfig from?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

try this

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def file = output.outputFile
        output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, file.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
    }
}
```

Comment: this actually fixed my issue, plus i had to set classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.2' in the android.gradle file

Comment: @Khalid Where to put it ?

Comment: Inside the ``android``-block of your script, there is a block ``buildTypes``. Inside that you can have blocks for any build configuration. In my case, the code resides inside ``release``.

Comment: This is a slightly misleading answer. Before you set the `applicationVariants` make sure have updated all your plugins or removed any you don't really need. In my case removing one misbehaving plugin and updating the others was enough to get the build working. After that adding or removing this block, using the more comprehensive example form @Chris, had no effect one way or the other. We'll see when I try to run the code but the gradle sync had no problems.

Comment: thanks - i upgraded an app from gradle 1.x to 2.3 and hit this error, so for whatever reason the code posted in the question works in the older gradle version but not 2.3 - this fixed me up.

Answer (score 21):

More comprehensively:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each  { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
    }
}
```

Comment: still got error while I'm on android studio 1.2beta, gradle plugin 1.0.1

Comment: same as this question, Could not find property 'outputFile' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl

Comment: Tricky situation, actually the forementioned solution always worked for me (on more than a dozen projects). However, here's a longshot: You could try and check your dependencies and update them to the most recent version. If your using multiple modules you may have an obsolete script hidden in one of them as well.

Answer (score 6):

This can occur for few reasons:

1.) First as was said before by [@Khalidov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2450439/khalidov-oleg), try

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFile = ...
    }
}
```

2.) Second try update all other plugins.

For example I got this problem for [Spoon](http://square.github.io/spoon/), that resolved by update Spoon up to:

```
classpath 'com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:0.14.1'
```

Answer (score 5):

Or where there's only one variant:

```
def apk = outputs[0].outputFile
```

Instead of

```
def apk = variant.outputFile
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run the latest gradle version (not the plugin, gradle it self).

Check your `gradle-wrapper.properties`. Are you running gradle 2.1?

More info on compatibility: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve as follows:

old:

```
buildTypes { 
libertação {

    runProguard false  // esta linha tem que ser mudado

    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile ( 'android.txt proguard-' ),  'proguard-rules.pro' 
}
```

}

new:

```
buildTypes { 
libertação {

    minifyEnabled false  // nova versão

    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile ( 'android.txt proguard-' ),  'proguard-rules.pro' 
}
```

}

edited in file buil.gradle of your project as described in this post by ruan65 
[Error:(26, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016385/error26-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard)

and after edit too this line:

```
applicationVariants . all { variant -> 
variant . outputs . each { output -> 
    def file = output . outputFile 
    output . outputFile =  new  File ( file . parent , file . name . replace ( ".apk" ,  "-"  + defaultConfig . versionName +  ".apk" )) 
}
```

}

as it was said up there.
That settled me!

Comment: Please explain your answer