# Could not find property 'outputFile' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl even by following the previous answers

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I had this infamous error when updating from AS 0.8 to Android Studio 1.0 RC4.

I saw already the question here: [Could not find property 'outputFile' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114073/could-not-find-property-outputfile-on-com-android-build-gradle-internal-api-ap)
and tried to adapt the code but with no success.

So I tried by commenting out the applicationVariants not to have this outputFile declared anywhere but still get the error (?)

Then I invalidate the cache using the option in *File-> Invalidate Caches / Restart* but again with no effect.

Finally i deleted the .gradle directory in my project folder but still got the error when trying to synchronise.

Do anyone have other suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the gradle plugins you are using (the buildscript dependencies from build.gradle) are all up to date and are adapted to work with gradle plugin 1.0.0.

I had the exact same problem and it was due to this fact. I was using an old version of `'com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin'`

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out the problem was in the android.gradle:

changing `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc4'`
with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.2'`
solved it

Comment: They are constantly tweaking Gradle plugin and its functions, so the cause of the problem is that the function you are using has been removed. It's not a good move to just go back to use old version instead of migrating to the latest one.