# Error Could not find property 'processManifest' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl

Tags: android, gradle

I already saw the answer: [Could not find property 'outputFile' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27114073/could-not-find-property-outputfile-on-com-android-build-gradle-internal-api-ap)
and tried to apply it, but with no success.

I'm migrating from gradle 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2' to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0', and not I'm getting the error

`Error:Could not find property 'processManifest' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@158aaf6.`

I've already renamed `runProguard` to `minifyEnabled`

```gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        // Spoon plugin of version 0.10.0 supports Android plugin 0.10.+
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.11.+'
        classpath 'com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:0.10.0'
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/"
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.02"
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
        instrumentTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    dependencies {
        androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.0.1'
    }
}

robolectric {
    include '**/*Test.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.0'
    compile 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
        }
    }
    // Espresso
    androidTestCompile files('lib/espresso-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-1.1.jar', 'lib/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1',
            'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1',
            'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'

    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-plugin-registry'
        exclude module: 'maven-profile'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'nekohtml'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-shared'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.7'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'spoon'

// This section is optional
spoon {
    // for debug output
    debug = true
    // To run a single test class
//    className = 'com.proverbed.budget.espresso.activity.AllTestsSuite'
    // To run a single method in TestCase
//    methodName = 'testAddIncome'
}

apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`, particularly your custom task or wherever you are using `processManifest`.

Comment: Hey CommonsWare, I've posted my build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

You are using old robolectric plugin 
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin/issues/120