# Android Studio Plugin issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am new in android studio I am importing a project i android studio and getting this issue.
You can see error.I did download new android Studio Bundle.Please help me in this.thanks

```
 Error:(23, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
 Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'shalomapps' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Comment: In any build.gradle files change runProguard to minifyEnabled.

Comment: i guess this may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016385/error26-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard

Comment: @Joel I changed now I am getting error
Error:Library projects cannot set applicationId. applicationId is set to 'com.shalom.shalombase' in default config.

Comment: Remove the applicationId line from any library build.gradle files.

Comment: @Joel thanks a lot I have solved from your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comments:

In any build.gradle files change runProguard to minifyEnabled. – [via @Joel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4170646/joel)