# build.gradle to support Google Play services?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm new to Android/Java programming, but have a complete Android app in the Play Store. So I wanted to add Google Cloud Messaging to my app, and that's when I ran into trouble. The various tutorials told me to get the Google Play services SDK and the Google Repository. Now when I try to build, I get 101 errors that I *think* is related to one or more of my build.gradle files. I've spent hours trying to fix this. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Here is the top of the message I see:

Error:Execution failed for task ':lib:processReleaseResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>     /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M /Users/scott/Documents/development/Android HVB/lib/build/bundles/release/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/scott/Documents/development/Android HVB/lib/build/res/all/release -A /Users/scott/Documents/development/Android HVB/lib/build/bundles/release/assets -m -J /Users/scott/Documents/development/Android HVB/lib/build/source/r/release --non-constant-id --output-text-symbols /Users/scott/Documents/development/Android HVB/lib/build/bundles/release

Here is the "app" build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.3a"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
    compile project(':lib')
}
```

Comment: Use this compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89' instead 6.5.+

Comment: Did you solved yet ?

Answer (score 1):

I describe this [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016385/error26-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard/27342403#27342403)

Just updated your build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
     buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            }
        }
```

Please update your manifest.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxxxx"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: I changed "runProguard false" to "minifyEnabled false" and now see the following (on 7 lines):

12:12:08 AM Gradle invocation completed successfully with 1 error(s) in 4 sec
12:12:11 AM Gradle 'Android HVB' project refresh failed:
            Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'minifyEnabled()'!
            Possible causes could be:  
            - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent 
            - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method
            - or there is a mistake in a build script

Comment: Thanks. I added "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+' " to the first line in dependencies {} and got the same error. Is that what you meant I should do?

Comment: Same results. I am frustrated. Going to bed.

Comment: In my application i use gms version this : Try once more . compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'

Comment: Use this classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'

Comment: I'm currently running an old version of Studio (0.5.2). Do I need to upgrade to v1? Apparently I can't just patch it. Do I just download the whole thing and run the installer?