# Android gradle, about those methods that are deprected after updating

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have encountered this problem several time whenever I update my Gradle version & Gradle Android plugin. For example, I used to use:

**Gradle** `2.1`

**Gradle Android Plugin** `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.3`

With this version, my build script contains for example:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), \
                          'proguard.cfg'
        }

        debug {
            runProguard false
        }

    }
```

Few weeks later, I saw a new Gradle version (2.2.1) was released, so, I updated my **Gradle** & **Gradle Android Plugin** to newer version:

**Gradle** `2.2.1`

**Gradle Android Plugin** `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+`

Then, I run command `gradle clean build`, suddenly, the build is not successful anymore, because with the newer version, I got error:

```
Could not find method runProguard()
```

My questions are:

1. (**MAIN QUESTION**) It seems everytime when the **Gradle** & **Gradle Android Plugin** are updated, there are always some methods are deprecated, it is understandable. BUT, I am really appreciate if there is a document summarizes all the deprecated methods & their replacements. So, where can I find such information? Seems Gradle & Gradle Android Plugin don't do a good job on this to facilitate developers to quickly migrate the build script to newer version.
2. How to get rid of the error: `Could not find method runProguard()` in my above case?

Comment: Duplicate of [Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016385/error26-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard)

Comment: @albemala, come on, my main question is to know where is the place to find out the replacements of deprecated methods in general when Gradle & Gradle Android Plugin are updated. Not only this specific case.  It is not a duplicated question.

Answer (score 1):

change

runProguard ****

to

minifyEnabled ****

you can get the deprecated methods or resources here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system for the android studio builds or releases

Comment: Thanks, but I can't accept your answer now, as I really want to know where is the place to find out the replacements of deprecated methods in general when Gradle & Gradle Android Plugin are updated. Not only this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

> I really want to know where is the place to find out the replacements of deprecated methods in general when Gradle & Gradle Android Plugin are updated

That would be the documentation, particularly [the release notes](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system). 0.14.0 renamed `runProguard` to `minifyEnabled`, and 0.14.3 removed `runProguard`.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `runProguard true` with `minifyEnabled true`, there are a lot of question about this topic.
On your first question, I read some official statement [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0) saying that, from now on, they'll try to stick to actual methods name and/or provide support info, to make the switch between gradle versions easier, so you shouldn't be worried.

> From version 1.0.0 and going forward, we will strive much harder to not make incompatible changes, and if we do, we plan to write IDE support to help migrate the projects automatically.

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0 this is what I was talking about.