# Add appcompat v7-22 to Android studio project

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-sdk-manager

Hi i want to use appcompatv7-22 in my app for that i use this gradle settings

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'

}
```

but when i run it i give this error message

```
Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+
```

i try this v7:22.0.0 and this v7:22.1.0 too but still same error
and this is my sdk maneger [image]
[image]
so can anyone help me.

**UPDATE**

i see my extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support folder but 21.03 there was  latest version. my repository version is 10 and i know its latest version so
where is
***com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0*** ?
***answer***
i found my problem at last thanks for dev answer my problem was support ripository library which last available version is 15 and my version was 9 and after update my problem solved.

Comment: Have you tried like this "compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'" ?

Comment: yes sorry about typing mistake

Comment: Well, which api level are you compiling with? Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29284236/failed-to-resolve-com-android-supportappcompat-v722-and-com-android-supportre

Comment: my compile api is 22 please see my updated question

Comment: @max hope now you using latest version ?

Answer (score 1):

**[v7 appcompat library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat)**

> This library adds support for the Action Bar user interface design
>   pattern. This library includes support for material design user
>   interface implementations.

Please **update your version**. Call this instead of yours.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

**Edit**

Call latest and stable version

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

And set  [minifyEnabled false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016385/error26-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard/27342403#27342403) .Then
 `Re-Build & Gradle & Restart` your Project

Comment: thanks for your answer but i use your answer but still same error

Comment: okay ,Let me try,set buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" and compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' .

Comment: set this,Like buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

Comment: The latest is `22.2.1`.

Comment: Hi Jared Burrows, how did you know the latest version is? Or at least the version list?

Comment: Find the latest version through Tools->Android->SDK Manager->SDK Tools tab.

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\Users\SysName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support
```

In windows, check this path. In support folder you can get appcompat lib or any support lib you want.In appcompat folder you can get list of versions you installed via sdk.

[image]

Get the version number and just mention the same version number in gradle settings like below. compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'`

Answer (score 0):

**Issue Description**:

Build - Build Output tab

> **Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0.**
>   
> Required by:
>       
> project :app
>   
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
>   Open Android SDK Manager

Build - Sync tab

> ERROR: **Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0**
>   
> *Add Google Maven repository and sync project*
>   
> Show in Project Structure dialog
>   
> Affected Modules: app

**Note**:

Android Support Repository is up to date (Version 47.0.0, July 2019)

**SOLUTION:** Include Google's Maven repository in your project's build.gradle file.

- Open build.gradle
- Add "google()" as shown below

> allprojects {
>       
>     repositories { 
>           
>         **google()**
>   
>     }
>   
> }

Source: [Adding Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup#add-library)